# Parent Child tables, adding child records for existing parent record add new parent records wrongly and then add child record

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

In EF I have two tables (parent is Office- child is Employee), I m adding  records to Employee with reference of existing Office record but I guess because of my wrong configuration EF is behaving wearied.

Instead of using Office table's existing record, it add a new records in Office and use new record's id as a foreign key in child records and then create child records.

Here are my Models:

```
public class Office
    {
        public int OfficeId{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }           
        public virtual IEnumerable<Employee> Employees{ get; set; }

    }


 public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID{ get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public int Age { get { return DOB.YearsFromUtcDateTillToday(); } }
        [NotMapped]
        public string FullName { get { return string.Concat(FirstName, ' ', LastName); } }
        public virtual Office Office { get; set; }

    }
```

View is strongly typed of `Employee` here is view code:

```
@model Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddEmployee";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.CodeTest.AddEmployee(),FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Office.OfficID)
    <fieldset>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GPA)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GPA)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GPA)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

My Controller Actions are the following:

```
 public virtual ActionResult AddEmployee(int officeId)
        {
            Employee st = new Employee();
            st.Office=new Office();
            st.Office.OfficeID= officeId;
            return View(st);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult AddEmployee(Employee objEmployee)
        {
           bool success= classEmployeeService.AddEmployee(objEmployee);
            if (success)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index",objEmployee.Office.OfficeId);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error! Business rule violation, can't repeat surname");
            }
            return View(objEmployee);

        }
```

**My Finding:**
In first action (without HttpPost) OfficeId is correct, 1 in this case
Checking html I came to know it is correct
But When pressing Save button 2nd action with HttpPost is executed OfficeId value is wrong, it is new Office record id (18, 19 or next record)

Please guide and help me.

Answer (score 0):

As i see you've an problem with your Model Design. The Employee class should has a property to represent the foreign key of OfficeID.

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID{ get; set; }
        public int OfficeID{ get; set; } // This what you need
        // ...... the rest of class properties 
    }
```

Then just assign the Office Id to this property not to the Navigation property "Office"

```
Employee st = new Employee();    
st.OfficeID= officeId;
```

And never use `st.Office=new Office();` because this will add this object to the DbContext StateManager as "Added" and it'll add it as new record to the Database.